# Landau Theory- Is order parameter extensive or intensive variable?

Tags: physics, problem-solving, statistical-mechanics

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

1) Is the order paramter $\phi(x)$ intensive or extensive?
2) Is $M$ intensive or extensive?

With the following definitions :

[image]

2. Relevant equations
3. The attempt at a solution

1) Free energy is extensive, however I don' think I can use this to deduce whether $\phi(x)$ is intensive or extensive via (1) since it will depend on the exact form of $W(\phi)$

Some texts say it's intensive and others extensive.

2) I believe $H$ the external field is intensive; and so since $M$ is it's conjugate variable via $M=\frac{\partial A}{\partial H}$ , $M$ must be extensive?

Any help much appreciated.